# How does array iteration work with "and"?

Tags: python, arrays

I wanted to iterate three items at a time through an array at +/-1 of the index if the index is valid. I came across this solution:

Example:

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range(len(A)):
   print(A[i and i-1:i+2])

#[0, 1]
#[0, 1, 2]
#[1, 2, 3]
#[2, 3, 4]
#[3, 4]
```

How does `A[i and i-1:i+2]` work? I am not sure how `A[0 and -1:2]` works in the array.

I took a look at the Python docs and says "The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned."
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and

However, this seems to be different with array splicing.

Comment: If you'll take a closer look, you'll see that it behaves exactly like the quote you brought in your question. Keep in mind that `0` is a "Falsy" value. So for example, `0 and -1` will return `0`. All the rest will always return the second number

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps looking at the output of the bounds of your slice will be helpful (I added parenthesis around the lower bound for clarity

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range(len(A)):
   print((i and i-1), i+2, A[(i and i-1):i+2])
```

This prints (comments mine):

```
0 2 [0, 1]    # lower bound => (0 and -1); 0 is falsy, so 0
0 3 [0, 1, 2] # lower bound => (1 and 0); 1 is true, so 0, based on your link
1 4 [1, 2, 3] # lower bound => (2 and 1); 2 is true, so 1, based on your link
2 5 [2, 3, 4] # ...
3 6 [3, 4]    # Degenerate slice indices (6) are handled gracefully
```